# How to replace annotation SpringBootTest if I have to wire up only one class, not the whole application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

I know if we use annotation `@SpringBootTest`, we wire up whole application.

But if I need to run just this class without launching the whole app, how can I replace `@SpringBootTest` ?

Comment: If you only need a single class, just create an instance yourself, inject mocks and run the test. You don't have to use spring for testing a simple unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ClassThatYouAreGoingToTest.class)`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ClassThatYouAreGoingToTest.class)
public class TestClass{
    @MockBean
    private BeanUsedInYourTestClass beanUsedInYourTestSubject;
    .....///another mock bean if required
    @Autowired
    private ClassThayYouAreGoingToTest testSubject;
   
///your @Tests

}
```

Comment: Which is only partially correct as only the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation wouldn't do a thing. You would also need either `@RunWith` or `@ExtendWith` depending on your Unit version.

Comment: Fixed, thank you